# Unable to sort data from txt flie using sort command in terminal

Tags: python, sorting, ubuntu, terminal

After extracting the data using the python code and then printing at Ubuntu terminal and then sorting using sort command in Ubuntu terminal, the data not properly sorting like  9 comes after the 99 etc(see the example below).

I am using below command in ubuntu terminal-->

```
python3 pythonfile.py file1.txt | sort
```

It's working fine if the -g parameter use in ubuntu terminal like below-->

```
python3 pythonfile.py file1.txt | sort -g
```

but i want to use only sort not any other parameters like-g(because we not allow to use that).

I want to just print the data at Ubuntu terminal and then sort it using `python3 pythonfile.py file1.txt | sort`

I don't want to save data in python code like "list" and then sort it and then print it in terminal.

Please give any suggestions how to sort data at Ubuntu terminal after printing there.

Below are the example after using `python3 pythonfile.py file1.txt | sort`
see last rows are nor properly sorted

```
 1. 980 E_4.802337379703114 981 C_-0.5174946578900912
    982 E_-0.04914191239380816 983  D_-0.681508079883169
    983 E_1.847345390268389 986 B_-0.36321505253912734
    986 D_0.8824340792739893 987    A_3.841576990884448
    987 D_2.8497812351372 988   B_4.548331946363086
    988 C_2.3889731803370955 989    B_2.118431924821179
    989 C_-0.07182437212394133 98   C_0.5129253356889238
    98  D_2.4529275958484718 990    B_3.6398151615539627
    990 C_-1.4798828718232553 990   D_3.249621796699633
    991 A_1.9238692496051026 991    D_4.974963953240026
    992 C_1.466211779881152 992 D_0.7144100838397083
    993 B_1.6590910160220598 994    B_3.840419732762326
    996 B_-0.2755606867866667 996   E_1.4732124728343967
    997 B_-0.4377938038287166 997   D_0.595186949529743
    997 E_-1.7359724002373582 998   D_3.502055570086875
    999 A_3.6392659412484214 999    C_-0.35184258330491924
    99  C_2.8983151961646527 99 E_-2.6201821295906322
    9   C_-0.1336234683083135 9 D_2.8068429946499425
    9   E_3.4384330848808187
```

Comment: Why don't you sort your data within your `pythonfile.py`? How are they stored? Please, consider also giving an example of `file1.txt` otherwise it will be hard for us all to guess what's wrong with both your code and your data.

Comment: And you should read the documentation of your command by typing this in a console; `man sort`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use numeric-sort: `sort -n`

`python3 pythonfile.py file1.txt | sort -n`